# Retrieving values from DBGrid in C++ Builder?

Tags: string, vector, datagrid, c++builder

I have a program written with C++Builder, where I load some user info in a table. I want to get the values from the column `password`, (***after retrieving them from the database but before  showing them on the DBGrid!***) and save each password as a string into an STL `vector`. However, I do not know how to get all the passwords (iterate through the rows) from that particular column (can be seen in the screenshot below). How can I do this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is this DbGrid, or regular grid ? What query are You using to retrieve data ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you:

```
ADOTable1->First();
for(int i = 0; i < ADOTable1->RecordCount; i++){
    UnicodeString password = ADOTable1->FieldByName("password")->AsString;
    // read other columns if necessary...
    ADOTable1->Next();
}
```

This will iterate through all database table records, starting from the first row until the last.